# AD administrator password out of sync between controllers and clients

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have found myself in an odd situation.

I have a development network of 15 Windows 2012 R2 servers on a HyperV virtualisation server.  There are two AD controllers for the single domain, and 13 servers linked to the domain.  This set up had worked perfectly fine for months.

Recently I moved home and the virtualisation server ended up being off for a prolonged period of time (a month).

Since I have fired the virtualisation server back up, I have had nothing but issues - the main one of which is that the non-domain-controller servers are not updating their domain administrator account password from the AD controllers.

I have changed the password (several times now) on the AD controllers but none of the non-domain-controllers reflect this update - they continue to use the domain administrator password from before the virtualisation server was turned off.

It has now been a week since I last changed the password on the AD controllers, a sync should definitely have happened by now.

All servers have static IP allocations from the network DHCP server (non-AD based).  All servers can ping each other and the AD controllers, all servers can RDP to each other and the AD controllers.  In all real terms, the network connection and virtual network is all working.

Can anyone shed any light?  Is there anything I can do to force a sync?

Comment: `the main one of which is that the non-domain-controller servers are not updating their domain administrator account password from the AD controllers` - That's not a thing. There is only one domain Administrator account. Each member computer does not have it's own domain Administrator account. Could it be that you're logging onto these member servers with the local Administrator account on each member server? `It has now been a week since I last changed the password on the AD controllers, a sync should definitely have happened by now.` - This also isn't a thing, for the reasons already stated.

Comment: If you are in fact logging on with the domain Administrator account, and you're doing so with the previous password, then my guess is that the member servers aren't actually communicating with your Domain Controllers and you're logging on with cached credentials. How are the DNS client settings configured on the member servers and on the Domain Controllers?

Comment: I know there is not multiple accounts, and I understand the concept of cached credentials - I am definitely logging onto the server using the AD administrator account.  The DNS settings on the servers with the issue point to the correct IP of the AD controllers.

Comment: Have you verified network connectivity between that member server and the Domain Controllers? What are the exact symptoms of the problem? What happens when you try logging onto the member servers with the new domain Administrator account password?

Comment: All those questions are answered in my original question - "All servers can ping each other and the AD controllers, all servers can RDP to each other and the AD controllers" & "I have changed the password (several times now) on the AD controllers but none of the non-domain-controllers reflect this update - they continue to use the domain administrator password from before the virtualisation server was turned off."

Comment: As an aside, I have now solved the issue.  Will detail in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have resolved this after coming to so many blanks.

It turns out that there was an external change that I was not aware of - the house move coincided with a new internet connection and thus a new router.  The new router seems to be providing IPv6 details via DHCP even though IPv6 is disabled in its DHCP settings.

Even though each and every server was configured correctly with IPv4 IP addresses and had proper IPv4 DNS settings for the AD controllers, they were defaulting to the provided IPv6 DNS settings and ignoring the IPv4 DNS settings - this put them out of contact with the AD controllers.

Disabling IPv6 on the affected servers immediately caused each server to pop up a "Windows needs your updated credentials, please lock this session and log in with your latest credentials" dialog, and the server does indeed now have the latest AD administrator credentials available and rejects the old credentials.

Job done.  Remember folks, watch out for third party systems which are not doing what they suggest they are doing.  IPv6 coming into play on the network was the issue here, without any suggestion that that was the issue.

Comment: Good find. My suggestion would be to disable DHCPv6 on the router and re-enable IPv6 on the servers.

Comment: That's the problem, it is disabled already :)